# User can't able to enter amount before currency symbol in textfield in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

[image]

Below is an image of the screen, I just want to when the user enters the amount on this textfield then the user can't able to move cursor before $ sign and can't able to write amount before $ sign.

Please have a look on my problem, and give me idea about it,

[image]

Comment: you can add a dollar image in that textfield.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stackoverflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: @GeneCode i dont ask for code, first look at my Decription,  i just asking about idea to make this things.

Comment: @R.Mohan but my textfield Alignment is center, so how can i set image..?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to set currency image as leftview of textfield

**For Imageview**

```
    UIImageView *imageArrow = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"currency.png"] ];
    UIView *paddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
    [paddingView addSubview:imageArrow];
    imageArrow.center = paddingView.center;
    textfield.leftView = paddingView;
    textfield.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

**For Label**

```
 UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
    label.text = @"$";
    textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
    textField.rightView = label;
```

Comment: @KK Rocks,  i have get one idea from your code. so thank you so much for you responds.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a textfield inside a view and before textfield add a lable with text "$". Remove the textfield border and add a border layer for view. It will work perfectly as per your requirement.

Answer (score -1):

You can use left view property of UITextField

```
 UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)];
    label.text = @"$";
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor white];
    textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
    textField.rightView = label;
```